# Javascript stop loop on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, function, loops, hover

I wanna make an element execute a function continuously while hovering my mouse and to stop executing it when I move my mouse away from it, but right now I can only start and no idea on how to make it stop

HTML:

```
<a onmouseover="randomizeHover(1)" id="link1" class="link" href="#">Home</a>
```

JS:

```
function randomize(id) {
  let element = document.getElementById("link" + id);
  element.innerHTML = "Ho" + makeid(2);
}

//generates random letters

function makeid(length) {
  var result = "";
  var characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var charactersLength = characters.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
  }
  return result;
}

//makes it repeat itself

function randomizeHover(id) {
  console.log("Hello?");
  setInterval(() => {
    randomize(id);
  }, 200);
}
```

Comment: setInterval returns an id that you can pass to clearInterval. Use that from your mouse out handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `mouseleave` event listener that clears the interval:

```js
function randomize(id) {
  let element = document.getElementById("link" + id);
  element.innerHTML = "Ho" + makeid(2);
}

//generates random letters

function makeid(length) {
  var result = "";
  var characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var charactersLength = characters.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
  }
  return result;
}

//makes it repeat itself

let interval;

function randomizeHover(id) {
  console.log("Hello?");
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    randomize(id);
  }, 200);
}
function stopRandomizer(){
  clearInterval(interval)
}
```

```html
<a onmouseover="randomizeHover(1)" onmouseleave="stopRandomizer()" id="link1" class="link" href="#">Home</a>
```

Comment: wouldn't addEventListener("mouseover", function ()... be a lot simpler